# Loop over arrays in a dataframe with an if statement

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write code that loops over the following code for columns in a dataframe: four times for four different arrays:

```py
median_alcohol = df.alcohol.median()
for i, alcohol in enumerate(df.alcohol):
    if alcohol >= median_alcohol:
        df.loc[i, 'alcohol'] = 'high'
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'alcohol'] = 'low'
df.groupby('alcohol').quality.mean()
```

The columns in the dataframe are:

```
alcohol
pH
residual_sugar
citric_acid
```

I am trying to come up with a method to capture the four different arrays. Any ideas how I should go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what actually you're trying to do, but, from what I understood, you could try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd 
from statistics import mean
df = pd.DataFrame({'alcohol':[45, 88, 56, 15, 71], 'pH':[12, 83, 56, 25,71],'residual_sugar':[14, 25, 55, 8, 21]}) 
print(df)
#Output
>>> alcohol  pH  residual_sugar
0      45    12   14
1      88    83   25
2      56    56   55
3      15    25    8
4      71    71   21

def func(colum):
    dftemp=df.copy()
    median_colum = eval('df.'+colum).median()
    for i, item in enumerate(eval('df.'+colum)):
        dftemp.loc[i, colum] = 'high' if item >= median_colum else 'low'
    return dftemp.groupby(colum).agg(list).applymap(mean)
    
    
differentarrays = [func(i) for i in df.columns]
for array in differentarrays:
    print(array)
```

Output:

```
           pH  residual_sugar
alcohol                      
high     70.0       33.666667
low      18.5       11.000000 


        alcohol  residual_sugar
pH                             
high  71.666667       33.666667
low   30.000000       11.000000 


                  alcohol    pH
residual_sugar                 
high            71.666667  70.0
low             30.000000  18.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def numeric_to_buckets(df, column_name):
median = df[column_name].median()
for i, val in enumerate(df[column_name]):
    if val >= median:
        df.loc[i, column_name] = 'high'
    else:
        df.loc[i, column_name] = 'low' 
for feature in df.columns[:-1]:
numeric_to_buckets(df, feature)
print(df.groupby(feature).quality.mean(), '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking for `np.where`, something along the lines of

```py
pd.DataFrame(np.where(df > df.median(), "high", "low"))
```